# Problems with defining profiles in pom.xml (Spring Boot)

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot application with two profiles: 'dev' and 'prod'. In 'dev' profile should be used H2 database, in 'prod' — PostgreSQL.

They are defined in pom.xml as following:

```
<profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>prod</id>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
                    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                    <version>9.4.1211.jre7</version>
                </dependency>

            </dependencies>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
                    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
</profiles>
```

No other databases are in pom.xml defined.

In my application.properties file 'prod' profile is defined as active:

```
spring.profiles.active = prod
```

Also I have two specific properties files for each profile:

application-dev.properties:

```
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
```

and application-prod.properties (I deploy my app to AWS):

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:postgresql://${RDS_HOSTNAME}:${RDS_PORT}/${RDS_DB_NAME}
spring.datasource.username = ${RDS_USERNAME}
spring.datasource.password = ${RDS_PASSWORD}
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
```

I start my IntelliJ IDEA with following VM-option:

```
-Dspring.profiles.active="dev"
```

When I start the program locally, I see that 'dev' profile is used (there is message in console "The following profiles are active: dev"), but H2 doesn't start. I become following error message:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE

Action:

        If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath.
    If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need
to active it (the profiles "dev" are currently active).
```

Please help me to define these profiles correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:h2:mem:yourDB
spring.datasource.driverClassName = org.h2.Driver
```

added in `application-dev.properties` file should solve your problem.

From [Spring Boot documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html), it may be needed in some cases :

> You often won’t need to specify the driver-class-name since Spring
>   boot can deduce it for most databases from the url.

**Edit**

Maven profile is not Spring Boot profile. 
when you run your project, enable also the maven profile with `-P` arg:

```
  mvn spring-boot:run -Pdev -Dspring.profiles.active="dev"
```

**Edit**

Update for handling production env problem.

Why overriding the version of postgresql provided by Spring in dependency?

Anyway, the version you use of postgresql driver has not the `org.postgresql.jdbc.Driver` class but `org.postgresql.Driver`.
So, specify that in the property file for prod config :

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName = org.postgresql.Driver
```

Comment: It gives the following error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: org.h2.Driver.

And in "org.h2.Driver" part 'h2.Driver' is red

Comment: Can you try to run your project outside IntelliJ ? Looks like a side-effect. Which SpringBoot version are you using ?

Comment: I'm using Spring Boot version v1.4.1.RELEASE. As I understand, Maven just doesn't add database dependency.

Comment: Maven profile is not Spring Boot profile. I updated my answer.

Comment: Hm, with `mvn spring-boot:run -Pdev -Dspring.profiles.active="dev"` it starts and works. Although tests aren't passing, thay cannot load ApplicationContext.

Comment: At last :) For tests executions, maybe some properties are missing in the dev profile.

Comment: It works, thank you. I've found out that for using it in IntelliJ the profile in the section Maven Project at the right side should be chosen.

Comment: Now it doesn't work in production (Amazon Elastic Beanstalk). I made 'prod' profile in pom.xml active by default (<activation>                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault></activation>) but it doesn't help. In AWS logs I see following: "Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: org.postgresql.jdbc.Driver". Full log is here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/23507764/ . Maybe I should provide some parameters while building .war file?

Comment: Because before, is it worked in the production config ?

Comment: No, it didn't. I was hoping that setting active profile in pom.xml will help.

Comment: It helps but it doesn't make everything :)  Look in the deployed war and check the postgres jar is present and inside, the driver class is also there.

Comment: postgresql-9.4.1212.jre7.jar is there, driver file isn't. Although I defined it in application-prod.properties as following: spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.jdbc.Driver. The words after 'org.' are red again(

Comment: thank you for your patience! Finally it works ok. The main point was that in moment of .war file building the Maven profile in Intellij should be set to 'prod'. In that case `spring.datasource.driverClassName = org.postgresql.Driver` in `application-prod.properties` turns green and everything works ok.

Comment: Great :) It is also an interesting subject for me as I often enough use PostgreSQL, h2 and springboot.  There, I learned something for the new driver class. So thank you too :)

Comment: As I understand, it's not necessary to define driver class in properties. In any case, it is still absent in the .war file, but everything works correctly. The main point is to build the .war file when Maven `prod` profile is chosen.

Comment: I used this one: http://mavenrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql/9.4.1212.jre7

Comment: Sorry,  bad manipulation.

Thank you for the feedback. I note it :) In official doc here : http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html, we can read : You often won’t need to specify the driver-class-name since Spring boot can deduce it for most databases from the url. So, I suppose it have to be true for most of DBMS but not all. Interesting, but I found it makes a little too many things.
In fact for information "org.postgresql.jdbc.Driver" doesn't exit for a long time. It is a very old version.